# Find shortest path with extra weight for each edge

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

> Given a UN-directed graph $G = (V , E)$, and each edge $e$ have two
> unique  positive weights. Given two vertices $s,t$, our goal is to
> find a shortest path from $s$ to $t$ such that if we traverse an edge
> for the first time, our algorithm use heaviest weight of that edge,
> but if we traverse more than one times, our algorithm use minimum
> weight of that edge. how we can compute shortest path in this graph?

Idea: run BFS for first time to traverse each edge to each lowest edge weight to active second weight of each edge that is minimum weight, now, run Dijkstra to find shortest path. But i think my idea is not true.